# Meteor - Running meteor on another port

Tags: meteor

I try to change the default port for meteor, but I dont' get it :

```
$ PORT='3510' meteor run --settings settings.json
[[[[[ ~/meteor/dorj ]]]]]                     

=> Started proxy.                             
=> A patch (Meteor 1.4.1.3) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

with settings.json being :

```
{
 "smtp"             :   {   "username"  :   "xxx"           ,
                                "password"  :   "xxx"           ,
                                "server"    :   "smtp.googlemail.com"    ,
                                "port"      :   465                      },
    "galaxy.meteor.com":    {
                                "env"       :   { 
                                                    "MONGO_URL" : "xxxx",
                                                    "MAIL_URL: "xxx"
                                                }
                            }
,
"private" : {"port" : 3510 }
,
"port" : 3510
}
```

I don't use galaxy as I am on my own private ubuntu server.

EDIT

As asked :

```
$run --port 3003 --settings settings.json
[[[[[ ~/meteor/dorj ]]]]]                     

=> Started proxy.                             
=> A patch (Meteor 1.4.1.3) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
   Starting your app                         |
```

make the "Starting your app" run forever :("

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try this and check if the port works?

```
meteor --port 8080
```

and if successful

```
meteor --port 8080 --settings settings.json
```

Comment: I have some variables that I need in settings.json so it doesn't work without the settings as parameters.